# Create and use composition class in Java to create and store objects using user-inputs

Tags: java, class, object, getter-setter, netbeans-8

I am trying to build an application that displays property listings, and allows the user to add a property, delete a property, or update one.

The **bolded** words are things I think should be Classes.

A **Property** has an **Address** and a **ViewingArrangement**.
An **Address** has a streetNumber, streetName, suburb and postalCode.
A **ViewingArrangement** has a **ContactPerson** and an openTime.
A **ContactPerson** has a name, officeLocation and phoneNumber.

My issue here is that, I don't know EXACTLY how to create a class that consists of an object of another class.
Eg. **ViewingArrangement** has an openTime, and **ContactPerson**, which is a class. 

How do I create **ViewingArrangement** class? How do I do the getter-setters, constructors etc? I've been trying and changing my program the entire day, I still can't quite get it right. I'm new, please help!

```
package PropertyListing.data;

public class ContactPerson {
String cpName;
String office;
String pNo;

public ContactPerson(String name, String off, String pno)
{
    String cpName = name;
    String office = off;
    String pNo = pno;
}

public void setCpName(String cpName) 
{
    this.cpName = cpName;
}

public String getCpName() 
{
    return cpName;
}

public String getOffice() 
{
    return office;
}

public void setOffice(String office) 
{
    this.office = office;
}

public String getPno() 
{
    return pNo;
}

public void setPno(String pno) 
{
    this.pNo = pno;
}
}
```

As follows is my ViewingArrangement class.. Please help :(

```
package PropertyListing.data;

public class ViewingArrangement {
String availTime;
private ContactPerson cp;

public ViewingArrangement (String availT, ContactPerson p)
{
  this.availTime = availT;
}

public String getVAtime ()
{
    return availTime;
}

public void setVAtime(String availTime)
{
    this.availTime = availTime;
}

public ContactPerson getCP()
{
    return cp;
}

public void setCP(ContactPerson cp)
{
    this.cp = cp;
}
```

The above are what I ended up after an entire day of messing around, googling and changing here and there, please go easy on me.

I hope that once I solve this issue, I can store my Property properly and my JList(I did setModel to DefaultListModel) would display the Property out nicely instead of displaying things like "PropertyListing.data.Property@55f716" etc. 

I really hope it is the aforementioned problem that I have that is causing this bad storing/displaying..

Answer (score 0):

Besides not making your objects' fields `private`, you're actually doing it pretty much right. So why isn't it "displaying" properly?

You're probably displaying your custom objects like `Strings`, using `System.out` or some GUI's `setText` method. This would work right, but you didn't tell your JVM how to print your object!

By default, when one of the aforementioned situations is executed, the object's `toString` method is called. This method is inherited from `Object`, and by default it prints some memory data about the object. `String` overwrites this by returning the characters it stores.

Your custom objects need to override `toString` to display properly. Here's an example for `ViewingArrangement` that you can tweak to your liking:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Viewing Arrangement: availTime - "+availtime+", Contact Person - "+cp;
}
```

When your `ContactPerson` class has its own overriden `toString` method, the above method will call that `toString` automatically because `cp` is being added onto a `String`!

`toString` shouldn't be depended on too much, though. You might consider having a utility class that formats each value of your "highest" class individually (in your case, it would be a `Property`), returning the then-readable `String`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a Property class that holds other Property classes, and it sounds like what you could use for it is called a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Instead of trying to create objects to hold all sorts of different instance data, you could instead make an object that holds "itself", so that you can put anything in the property fields and still be able to access your data easily. A Tree is helpful for this implementation because you can both hold properties that are made of more properties and single property fields.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Property {

    private Map<String, Property> properties;
    private String data;

    public Property() {

            properties = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
            data = null;

    }

    public void setData(String propertyName, String newData) {

        // if we can find another field to put this in, do so. Else, store it in this property.
        if (!properties.containsKey(propertyName)
            properties.get(propertyName).setData(newData);
        else
            data = newData;
    }

    public String getData(String key) {

        properties.get(key).getData();

    }

}
```

Using this, you can effectively (and recursively!) create a tree of properties that you can store and reference with this. A class like this could be modified to fit whatever else you need to store. Hope this helps!